# Errors with default Android Studio projects

Tags: java, android, startup

When I create standard (any) project in Android studio and launch it, I get many errors.

```js
:app:clean
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2321Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72321Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42321Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2321Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources
:app:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies
:app:mockableAndroidJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources
:app:buildInfoDebugLoader
:app:transformClassesWithExtractJarsForDebug
:app:transformClassesWithInstantRunVerifierForDebug
:app:transformClassesWithJavaResourcesVerifierForDebug
:app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
:app:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug
:app:transformResourcesAndNative_libsWithJavaResourcesVerifierForDebug
:app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug
:app:transformClasses_enhancedWithInstant+reloadDexForDebug
:app:incrementalDebugTasks
:app:prePackageMarkerForDebug
:app:coldswapKickerDebug
:app:fastDeployDebugExtractor
:app:generateDebugInstantRunAppInfo
:app:transformClassesWithInstantRunSlicerForDebug
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug
Error:java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
Error: at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
Error: at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
Error: at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
Error: at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
Error: at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
Error: at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
Error: at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
Error: at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
Error: at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
Error: at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
Error: at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
Error: at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
Error: at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
Error:Exception in thread "main" 
Error:java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
Error: at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
Error: at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
Error: at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
Error: at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
* What went wrong:
Error: at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
Error: at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Error: at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
Error: at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
* Try:
Error: at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Error: at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
Error: at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
Error: at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
Error:Exception in thread "main" 
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 3.238 secs
Error:java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
Error: at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
Error: at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
Error: at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
Error: at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
Error: at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
Error: at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
Error: at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
Error: at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
Error: at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
Error: at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
Error: at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
Error: at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
Error: at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
Error:Exception in thread "main" 
Information:44 errors
```

With my old projects it works fine. With new created by A.S "make project" it looks ok, but when I launch it at emulator it starts but I have over 100 console errors.

Could you tell me what's a problem here, or I have to reinstall it?

Comment: Change the JDK location to new version (i.e >1.6). 
You change it on Studio going **File > Project Structure > SDK Location**
make like _C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60_

have a look this post [unsupportedclasserror](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2906852/5955593)

Comment: Included the console errors in the post as a code snippet for later reference when the txt URL gives a 404.

Comment: Frank. i ve tried gives error.

Answer (score 0):

on your gradle are you working with buildToolsVersion 24 RC1 ? if yes change it to  '23.0.2' and compile with jdk 1.7